SQL Summarise Duration Periods Across Multiple Time Periods By Various Attributes
I have updated the script below based on advice provided in the comments. Any further help would be greatly appreciated.
I am attempting to analyse periods of Production and Downtime in a manufacturing environment.
I have the Start and End DateTimes of these periods with a SHIFT, TYPE & REASON assigned. I need to split up the TOTAL Duration across both SHIFTS, TYPE & REASON, so I can allocate the information at each of those levels.
Action_Types are Grouped into 'Production' and 'Downtime' with Action_Type_Groups then describing the reason for Action. (Primarily aimed at downtime reasons).
To complicate matters the SHIFTS are split between DAY & Night which run from 06:00 - 18:00 and 18:00 - 06:00 respectively.
Below is a sample of example data and the output of where I have got to so far. BUT I am unsure as to how to produce the output image you will see below / attached.
I need to be able to query the above 3 aspects of the data across SHIFTS, TYPE & REASON, but also will need to query mid way points (days / shifts) where a period of activity lasts many days. (items 7 & 8 below)
I have added some notes in the script if that helps.
BELOW / ATTACHED IMAGE IS WHAT I WOULD EXPECT THE FINAL DATA TO LOOK LIKE.
I have left the original ROWS in for reference only but are not required.
Any help would be greatly received.
Thank you

  CREATE TABLE TEST_Table 
  
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Action_StartDate DATETIME,
    Action_EndDate DATETIME,
    Duration  int,
    Machine_No int,
    Action_Type varchar (15),
    Action_Type_Reason varchar (15),
    Senario_Comment_For_Info Varchar (100) 
)

--PLEASE NOTE 
--SHIFTS RUN FROM:
--06:00 - 17:59 (DAY SHIFT)
--18:00 - 05:59 (NIGHT SHIFT)
--ANY ACTIVTY THAT IS FROM 00:00 - 05:59 IS CLASSED AS PREVIOUS DAYS SHIFT 

            INSERT INTO TEST_Table (ID, Action_StartDate, Action_EndDate, Duration, Machine_No, Action_Type, Action_Type_Reason, Senario_Comment_For_Info )
            VALUES 
            ('1','2024-10-14 10:15:00', '2024-10-14 13:00:00', '','10', 'Production', 'Production' , 'Action Type Within Same Shift'),
            ('2','2024-10-14 07:00:00', '2024-10-14 10:15:00', '','10', 'Down Time',  'Power Failure',  'Action Type Within Same Shift'),
            ('3','2024-10-15 05:30:00', '2024-10-15 12:30:00', '','20', 'Production', 'Production' , 'Action Type Spanning 2 Shifts (same calendar day)'),
            ('4','2024-10-15 03:00:00', '2024-10-15 12:45:00', '','20', 'Down Time',  'Material Fault',  'Action Type Spanning 2 Shifts (same calendar day)'),
            ('5','2024-10-16 20:15:00', '2024-10-17 03:30:00', '','30', 'Production', 'Production', 'Action Type Spanning Same Shift (diff calendar day)'),
            ('6','2024-10-17 20:00:00', '2024-10-18 01:15:00', '','30', 'Down Time',  'Machine Fail',  'Action Type Spanning Same Shift (diff calendar day)'),
            ('7','2024-10-14 10:15:00', '2024-10-18 12:15:00', '','40', 'Production', 'Production', 'Action Type Spanning Multiple Days and Shifts'),
            ('8','2024-10-15 10:00:00', '2024-10-18 12:00:00', '','40', 'Down Time',  'Machine Fail',    'Action Type Spanning Multiple Days and Shifts')

-----------------------------
Create table Shift_Types  -- All avialable Values

(
    Shift_Flag varchar (15)
)

            INSERT INTO Shift_Types (Shift_Flag)
            VALUES 

            ('Day Shift'),
            ('Night Shift')


-----------------------------
Create table Action_Types  -- All avialable Values

(
Action_Type varchar (15),
Action_Type_Reason varchar (15),
)

            INSERT INTO Action_Types (Action_Type, Action_Type_Reason)
            VALUES 
            ('Production','Production'),
            ('Down Time','Power Failure'),
            ('Down Time','Material Fault'),
            ('Down Time','Machine Fail')

-----------------------------

Create table Shift_Dates -- All avialable Values

(
Shift_Date  Date,
Shift_Type  varchar (15),
Shift_Start_Time  datetime,
Shift_End_Time  datetime
)

            Insert into Shift_Dates (Shift_Date, Shift_Type, Shift_Start_Time, Shift_End_Time)
            Values

            ('2024-10-14','Day Shift','2024-10-14 06:00:00','2024-10-15 17:59:59'),
            ('2024-10-14','Night Shift','2024-10-14 18:00:00','2024-10-15 05:59:59'),
            ('2024-10-15','Day Shift','2024-10-15 06:00:00','2024-10-16 17:59:59'),
            ('2024-10-15','Night Shift','2024-10-15 18:00:00','2024-10-16 05:59:59'),
            ('2024-10-16','Day Shift','2024-10-16 06:00:00','2024-10-17 17:59:59'),
            ('2024-10-16','Night Shift','2024-10-16 18:00:00','2024-10-17 05:59:59'),
            ('2024-10-17','Day Shift','2024-10-17 06:00:00','2024-10-18 17:59:59'),
            ('2024-10-17','Night Shift','2024-10-17 18:00:00','2024-10-18 05:59:59'),
            ('2024-10-18','Day Shift','2024-10-18 06:00:00','2024-10-19 17:59:59'),
            ('2024-10-18','Night Shift','2024-10-18 18:00:00','2024-10-19 05:59:59')




UPDATE TEST_Table
SET Duration = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Action_StartDate, Action_EndDate)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------

---- Cross Join to get all available options
--select *, 720 as Available_mins -- added the available mins in so i can calculate mins per day % per Action_Type
--from --TEST_Table
---- Shift_Types
----cross join 
--Action_Types
--cross join Shift_Dates
--order by Shift_Date
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- This gives my raw DEMO data

SELECT        
ID, 
Action_StartDate,
Action_EndDate,

-- This Case statement allocates the previous days date if STARTDATE (hour) between midnight and 6am. 
case 
when Datepart (HH, Action_StartDate) <= 5 then Cast (Action_StartDate -1 as Date ) 
else cast (Action_StartDate as date)   
end as Allocated_Shift_Date,

-- Identifies DAY Shift / NIGHT shift.
case 
when Datepart (HH, Action_StartDate) between 6 and 17 then 'Day Shift' 
when Datepart (HH, Action_StartDate) < 6 or Datepart (HH, Action_StartDate) > 17 then 'Night Shift' 
else 'Shift Error'
end as Shift_Flag,

Machine_No,
Action_Type, 
Action_Type_Reason,

Duration as Duration_Mins,
Duration / 60 as Duration_Hours, 
Senario_Comment_For_Info
FROM TEST_Table

-- Potential Solution Script ???? Not working 
-- I need to be able to split the times across the the APO (All Possible Outcomes) Table ?????

select * 

from 

            (
            -- Cross Join to get all available options
            select *, 720 as Available_mins -- added the available mins in so i can calculate mins per day % per Action_Type
            from --TEST_Table
            -- Shift_Types
            --cross join 
            Action_Types
            cross join Shift_Dates
            --order by Shift_Date
            )  as APO -- All_Possible_Outcomes

left outer join TEST_Table as TT

on APO.Shift_Type = 
case 
when Datepart (HH, TT.Action_StartDate) between 6 and 17 then 'Day Shift' 
when Datepart (HH, TT.Action_StartDate) < 6 or Datepart (HH, TT.Action_StartDate) > 17 then 'Night Shift' 
else 'Shift Error'
end

and 

APO.Shift_Date = 
case 
when Datepart (HH, TT.Action_StartDate) <= 5 then Cast (TT.Action_StartDate -1 as Date ) 
else cast (TT.Action_StartDate as date)   
end

and APO.Action_Type_Reason = TT.Action_Type_Reason

order by 3, 4 desc 

drop Table TEST_Table
drop Table Action_Types
drop Table Shift_Types
drop table Shift_Dates


Create a table containing one row per shift, ie two rows per day, or whatever. Then you can join that to get every shift that each event overlaps.

Thanks for your reply. Would i then need to create the same table / rows  for every eventuality of the SHIFTS, TYPE & REASON also ??

Please don't use images for data, use table markdown.

IF you have source data that spans a shift boundary, AND you need the partial durations assigned into day or night shift, THEN it would be helpful to have a table with each shift. You could also make a table of every Type, and another of every Reason, then cross join all three (shifts, types, reasons) but you would only need to do so if your reporting REQUIRES that the full set of Types and/or full set of Reasons exist in the final report. i.e. without these 2 extra tables analysis would only include Types or Reasons that exist in the selected source data.

Hi, apologies for delay in coming back to you. Thanks for your advice @Paul Maxwell. I have updated my script as per your advice above, but i am still unsure as to how to link the 2 tables to get the desired output. Any further advice would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Looks like some of your test data for shifts is off. I haven't checked everything but that may be a piece of it.

I've been tinkering with this and found a solution. I'm not sure that it is the most efficient but the key to it all was adding indicators and flags. These helped me in determining the total time an action and shift took place. Also, it appeared that some of your test data was off. I called it out in a previous comment (mainly the shift start and end dates). Also, you image of the spreadsheet has some data issues. Look at 8.7's action end date.
CREATE TABLE #TEST_Table

  

(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Action_StartDate DATETIME,
    Action_EndDate DATETIME,
    Duration  int,
    Machine_No int,
    Action_Type varchar (15),
    Action_Type_Reason varchar (15),
    Scenario_Comment_For_Info Varchar (100)
)
 
--PLEASE NOTE
--SHIFTS RUN FROM:
--06:00 - 17:59 (DAY SHIFT)
--18:00 - 05:59 (NIGHT SHIFT)
--ANY ACTIVTY THAT IS FROM 00:00 - 05:59 IS CLASSED AS PREVIOUS DAYS SHIFT
 
            INSERT INTO #TEST_Table (ID, Action_StartDate, Action_EndDate, Duration, Machine_No, Action_Type, Action_Type_Reason, Scenario_Comment_For_Info )
            VALUES
            ('1','2024-10-14 10:15:00', '2024-10-14 13:00:00', '','10', 'Production', 'Production' , 'Action Type Within Same Shift'),
            ('2','2024-10-14 07:00:00', '2024-10-14 10:15:00', '','10', 'Down Time',  'Power Failure',  'Action Type Within Same Shift'),
            ('3','2024-10-15 05:30:00', '2024-10-15 12:30:00', '','20', 'Production', 'Production' , 'Action Type Spanning 2 Shifts (same calendar day)'),
            ('4','2024-10-15 03:00:00', '2024-10-15 12:45:00', '','20', 'Down Time',  'Material Fault',  'Action Type Spanning 2 Shifts (same calendar day)'),
            ('5','2024-10-16 20:15:00', '2024-10-17 03:30:00', '','30', 'Production', 'Production', 'Action Type Spanning Same Shift (diff calendar day)'),
            ('6','2024-10-17 20:00:00', '2024-10-18 01:15:00', '','30', 'Down Time',  'Machine Fail',  'Action Type Spanning Same Shift (diff calendar day)'),
            ('7','2024-10-14 10:15:00', '2024-10-18 12:15:00', '','40', 'Production', 'Production', 'Action Type Spanning Multiple Days and Shifts'),
            ('8','2024-10-15 10:00:00', '2024-10-18 12:00:00', '','40', 'Down Time',  'Machine Fail',    'Action Type Spanning Multiple Days and Shifts')
 
-----------------------------
Create table #Shift_Types  -- All avialable Values
 
(
    Shift_Flag varchar (15)
)
 
            INSERT INTO #Shift_Types (Shift_Flag)
            VALUES
 
            ('Day Shift'),
            ('Night Shift')
 
 
-----------------------------
Create table #Action_Types  -- All avialable Values
 
(
Action_Type varchar (15),
Action_Type_Reason varchar (15),
)
 
            INSERT INTO #Action_Types (Action_Type, Action_Type_Reason)
            VALUES
            ('Production','Production'),
            ('Down Time','Power Failure'),
            ('Down Time','Material Fault'),
            ('Down Time','Machine Fail')
 
-----------------------------
 
Create table #Shift_Dates -- All avialable Values
 
(
Shift_Date  Date,
Shift_Type  varchar (15),
Shift_Start_Time  datetime,
Shift_End_Time  datetime
)
 
            Insert into #Shift_Dates (Shift_Date, Shift_Type, Shift_Start_Time, Shift_End_Time)
            Values
 
            ('2024-10-14','Day Shift','2024-10-14 06:00:00','2024-10-14 17:59:59'),
            ('2024-10-14','Night Shift','2024-10-14 18:00:00','2024-10-15 05:59:59'),
            ('2024-10-15','Day Shift','2024-10-15 06:00:00','2024-10-15 17:59:59'),
            ('2024-10-15','Night Shift','2024-10-15 18:00:00','2024-10-16 05:59:59'),
            ('2024-10-16','Day Shift','2024-10-16 06:00:00','2024-10-16 17:59:59'),
            ('2024-10-16','Night Shift','2024-10-16 18:00:00','2024-10-17 05:59:59'),
            ('2024-10-17','Day Shift','2024-10-17 06:00:00','2024-10-17 17:59:59'),
            ('2024-10-17','Night Shift','2024-10-17 18:00:00','2024-10-18 05:59:59'),
            ('2024-10-18','Day Shift','2024-10-18 06:00:00','2024-10-18 18:59:59'),
            ('2024-10-18','Night Shift','2024-10-18 18:00:00','2024-10-19 05:59:59')
 
 
UPDATE #TEST_Table
SET Duration = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Action_StartDate, Action_EndDate)
 
 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
---- Cross Join to get all available options
--select *, 720 as Available_mins -- added the available mins in so i can calculate mins per day % per Action_Type
--from --TEST_Table
---- Shift_Types
----cross join
--Action_Types
--cross join Shift_Dates
--order by Shift_Date

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-- This gives my raw DEMO data


-- action data
       SELECT   ID                                              ID
                ,Action_StartDate                               Action_StartDate
                ,Action_EndDate                                 Action_EndDate

                -- This Case statement allocates the previous days date if STARTDATE (hour) between midnight and 6am.
                ,case
                    when Datepart (HH, Action_StartDate) <= 5 then Cast (Action_StartDate -1 as Date )
                    else cast (Action_StartDate as date)  
                end                                             Allocated_Shift_Date
 
                -- Identifies DAY Shift / NIGHT shift.
                ,case
                    when Datepart (HH, Action_StartDate) between 6 and 17 then 'Day Shift'
                    when Datepart (HH, Action_StartDate) < 6 or Datepart (HH, Action_StartDate) > 17 then 'Night Shift'
                    else 'Shift Error'
                end                                             Shift_Flag
 
                ,Machine_No                                     Machine_No
                ,Action_Type                                    Action_Type
                ,Action_Type_Reason                             Action_Type_Reason
                    
                ,Duration                                       Duration_Mins
                ,Duration / 60.0                                Duration_Hours
                ,Scenario_Comment_For_Info                      Scenario_Comment_For_Info
        into    #events
        FROM    #TEST_Table


;with _init as
(   -- Initial batch of data with indicators to identify whether multi days/shifts were crossed and the action/shift starts/ends were used for the join
    select      ID                                                                                                                              ID
                ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by a.ID order by b.Shift_Start_Time)                                                              PID
                ,Action_StartDate                                                                                                               Action_StartDate
                ,Action_EndDate                                                                                                                 Action_EndDate  
                ,b.Shift_Start_Time                                                                                                             Shift_Start_Time
                ,b.Shift_End_Time                                                                                                               Shift_End_Time
                ,Allocated_Shift_Date                                                                                                           Allocated_Shift_Date
                ,Shift_Flag                                                                                                                     Shift_Flag
                ,Machine_No                                                                                                                     Machine_No
                ,Action_Type                                                                                                                    Action_Type
                ,Action_Type_Reason                                                                                                             Action_Type_Reason
                -- determining if the action crossed multiple days
                ,iif(DATEDIFF(day,a.Action_StartDate,a.Action_EndDate) > 0,'X',null)                                                            Mult_Day_Ind
                -- determining if the action cross multiple shifts
                ,IIF(Shift_Cnt > 1,'X',null)                                                                                                    Mult_Shift_Ind
                ,c.Shift_Cnt                                                                                                                    Shift_Cnt


                -- Below indicators are used to calculate  minutes and hours 
                -- A1 = Action Start Date
                -- A2 = Action End Date
                -- S1 = Shift Start Date
                -- S2 = Shift End Date
                ,iif(b.Shift_Start_Time between a.Action_StartDate and a.Action_EndDate,'X',null)   S1
                ,iif(b.Shift_End_Time between a.Action_StartDate and a.Action_EndDate  ,'X',null)   S2
                ,iif(a.Action_StartDate between b.Shift_Start_Time and b.Shift_End_Time,'X',null)   A1
                ,iif(a.Action_EndDate between b.Shift_Start_Time and b.Shift_End_Time  ,'X',null)   A2

    from        #events         a
    left join   #Shift_Dates    b      on       b.Shift_Start_Time between a.Action_StartDate and a.Action_EndDate
                                            or  b.Shift_End_Time between a.Action_StartDate and a.Action_EndDate
                                            or  a.Action_StartDate between b.Shift_Start_Time and b.Shift_End_Time
                                            or  a.Action_EndDate between b.Shift_Start_Time and b.Shift_End_Time
    outer apply (   -- Determines the shift counts between each action
                    select  COUNT(*)    Shift_Cnt
                    from    #Shift_Dates    c
                    where   c.Shift_Start_Time between a.Action_StartDate and a.Action_EndDate
                        or  c.Shift_End_Time between a.Action_StartDate and a.Action_EndDate
                        or  a.Action_StartDate between c.Shift_Start_Time and c.Shift_End_Time
                        or  a.Action_EndDate between c.Shift_Start_Time and c.Shift_End_Time
                )               c

)


-- Detail level that shows calculated minutes and hours based on above indicators
select  a.*
into    #detail
from    (
            select  ID
                    ,PID
                    ,Action_StartDate
                    ,Action_EndDate      
                    ,Allocated_Shift_Date
                    ,Shift_Flag
                    ,Machine_No
                    ,Action_Type
                    ,Action_Type_Reason
                    -- calculating production minutes by shift
            
                    ,case
                        when    -- Action occurred during one shift and one day
                                Mult_Shift_Ind is null and Mult_Day_Ind is null then DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Action_StartDate,Action_EndDate)
                        when    -- Action occurred during one shift and multiple days (leads to the need of a union)
                                Mult_Shift_Ind is null and Mult_Day_Ind = 'x' then DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Action_StartDate,cast(Action_EndDate as date))
                        when    -- Full shift occurred during action
                                S1 = 'x' and S2 = 'x' then DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Shift_Start_Time,Shift_End_Time) + 1
                        when    -- Action started during shift but ended during a different shift
                                A1 = 'x' and S2 = 'x' then DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Action_StartDate,Shift_End_Time) + 1

                        when    -- Action started during shift but ended during a different shift
                                A2 = 'x' and S1 = 'x' then DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Shift_Start_Time,Action_EndDate)
                        --else  0
                                
                    end                                             Duration_Mins
                    ,case
                        when    -- Action occurred during one shift and one day
                                Mult_Shift_Ind is null and Mult_Day_Ind is null then DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Action_StartDate,Action_EndDate)
                        when    -- Action occurred during one shift and multiple days (leads to the need of a union)
                                Mult_Shift_Ind is null and Mult_Day_Ind = 'x' then DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Action_StartDate,cast(Action_EndDate as date))
                        when    -- Full shift occurred during action
                                S1 = 'x' and S2 = 'x' then DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Shift_Start_Time,Shift_End_Time) + 1
                        when    -- Action started during shift but ended during a different shift
                                A1 = 'x' and S2 = 'x' then DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Action_StartDate,Shift_End_Time) + 1

                        when    -- Action started during shift but ended during a different shift
                                A2 = 'x' and S1 = 'x' then DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Shift_Start_Time,Action_EndDate)
                        --else  0
                                
                    end / 60.0                                      Duration_Hours
                    ,case
                        when A1 = 'x' and A2 = 'x' and coalesce(Mult_Shift_Ind,Mult_Day_Ind) is null then 'Action Type Within Same Shift - These are OK as they are'
                        when Mult_Shift_Ind = 'x' and Mult_Day_Ind is null then 'Split from Above' -- 'Action Type Spanning 2 Shifts (same calendar day)'
                        when Mult_Shift_Ind is null and Mult_Day_Ind = 'x' then 'Split from Above' -- 'Action Type Spanning Same Shift (diff calendar day)'
                        
                        --when Mult_Shift_Ind = 'x' and Mult_Day_Ind = 'x' then 'Action Type Spanning Multiple Days and Shifts'
                        when    -- Full shift occurred during action
                                S1 = 'x' and S2 = 'x' then  FORMAT(Shift_Start_Time,'HH:mm') + ' - ' + FORMAT(dateadd(minute,1,Shift_End_Time),'HH:mm') -- DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Shift_Start_Time,Shift_End_Time) + 1
                        when    -- Action started during shift but ended during a different shift
                                A1 = 'x' and S2 = 'x' then FORMAT(Action_StartDate,'HH:mm') + ' - ' + FORMAT(dateadd(minute,1,Shift_End_Time),'HH:mm') -- DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Action_StartDate,Shift_End_Time) + 1
                        when    -- Action started during shift but ended during a different shift
                                A2 = 'x' and S1 = 'x' then FORMAT(Shift_Start_Time,'HH:mm') + ' - ' + FORMAT(Action_EndDate,'HH:mm') -- DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Shift_Start_Time,Action_EndDate)
                        --else  0
                                
                    end Scenario_Comment_For_Info
                    --,A1
                    --,A2
                    --,S1
                    --,S2
                    ,Mult_Shift_Ind
                    ,Mult_Day_Ind
            from    _init

            union 

            -- Used to bring in split lines for same shift but differing days
            select  ID
                    ,2
                    ,Action_StartDate
                    ,Action_EndDate      
                    ,Allocated_Shift_Date
                    ,Shift_Flag
                    ,Machine_No
                    ,Action_Type
                    ,Action_Type_Reason
                    -- calculating production minutes by shift
            
                    ,case
                        when    -- Action occurred during one shift and multiple days (leads to the need of a union)
                                Mult_Shift_Ind is null and Mult_Day_Ind = 'x' then DATEDIFF(MINUTE,cast(Action_EndDate as date),Action_EndDate)
                                
                    end                                             Duration_Mins
                    ,case
                        when    -- Action occurred during one shift and multiple days (leads to the need of a union)
                                Mult_Shift_Ind is null and Mult_Day_Ind = 'x' then DATEDIFF(MINUTE,cast(Action_EndDate as date),Action_EndDate)
                                
                    end / 60.0                                      Duration_Hours
                    ,'Split from Above'                             Scenario_Comment_For_Info   -- 'Action Type Spanning Same Shift (diff calendar day)'
                    --,A1
                    --,A2
                    --,S1
                    --,S2
                    ,Mult_Shift_Ind
                    ,Mult_Day_Ind


            from    _init
            where   Mult_Shift_Ind is null
                and Mult_Day_Ind = 'x'

    )   a



-- Final product
select  a.*
from    (
            select  distinct
                    cast(ID as varchar(500)) + '.0' ID
                    ,Action_StartDate
                    ,Action_EndDate
                    ,Allocated_Shift_Date
                    ,Shift_Flag
                    ,Machine_No
                    ,Action_Type
                    ,Action_Type_Reason
                    ,sum(Duration_Mins) over (partition by ID order by ID)  Duration_Mins
                    ,sum(Duration_Hours) over (partition by ID order by ID) Duration_Hours
                    ,case
                        when Mult_Shift_Ind = 'x' and Mult_Day_Ind is null then 'Action Type Spanning 2 Shifts (same calendar day)'
                        when Mult_Shift_Ind is null and Mult_Day_Ind = 'x' then 'Action Type Spanning Same Shift (diff calendar day)'
                        when Mult_Shift_Ind = 'x' and Mult_Day_Ind = 'x' then 'Action Type Spanning Multiple Days and Shifts'
                        else Scenario_Comment_For_Info
                    end     Scenario_Comment_For_Info
            from    #detail

            union all

            select  cast(ID as varchar(500)) + '.' + cast(PID as varchar(8))
                    ,Action_StartDate
                    ,Action_EndDate
                    ,Allocated_Shift_Date
                    ,Shift_Flag
                    ,Machine_No
                    ,Action_Type
                    ,Action_Type_Reason
                    ,Duration_Mins
                    ,Duration_Hours
                    ,Scenario_Comment_For_Info
            from    #detail
    )   a
order by    a.ID





drop Table  #TEST_Table
            ,#Action_Types
            ,#Shift_Types
            ,#Shift_Dates
            ,#events
            ,#detail

